# Send email with parameterized jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration

I have created a parameterized jenkins job where one of the parameters is the users email address. I want to notify the user if the build fails via email. In the configuration, I see a checkbox named "Send separate e-mails to individuals who broke the build." I have this checked. However, I am not receiving an email when my email is in the parameter and I break the build. If you need more info, let me know.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which email notification plugin are you using ?

I use editable email ext plugin and the fields to send emails can take values like $DEFAULT_RECIPIENTS etc

[image: Jenkins Email Ext Plugin configuration in the Job]

Comment: I just have one field: Recipients. Would it be possible add the email paramater to the recipient field?

Comment: I added $email in the recipients field and it pulled in the email from the param...